# Modal windows appearing behind others in Windows 7

Tags: .net, winforms, windows-7

I have been seeing some strange modality issues in Windows 7. A couple of C# programs I have written show a form with ShowDialog. The form appears as expected. Every so often, and it is usually when the app has been left to its own devices, the modal dialog moves behind the calling form. Of course it looks like the program has locked up because the calling form doesn't have focus and just beeps when clicked. The modal form can be brought to the front. I *think* I have seen this in other, non .NET programs too.  Anyone else seen this?

[image: Picture showing a Spy++ of it happening. The owner of 'BackupFiles' is 'Choose Places to Backup' is in front]

Comment: Did you remember to pass the correct owner window to `ShowDialog`?

Comment: I just called ShowDialog() from my main form. According to the docs "When this version is called, the currently active window is made the owner of the dialog box.". I took that to mean that ShowDialog() and ShowDialog(this) would be equivalent.

Comment: They are not equivalent if the calling form is not the active window. For example, it may have lost activation to another window. (The screen saver?)

Comment: I saw another example today. I have a utility that downloads media onto a PC. I started it off and when i came back the modal 'copying' form was behind the main form. The main form issued the ShowDialog() ... and was the active window at the time.

Comment: This still happens in  my app. I call the dialog with:

            CopyMedia Copier = new CopyMedia(AutoClose);
            Copier.ShowDialog(this);

Where CopyMedia is the form I want to show and 'this' is the current (and top level) window. One thing I have noticed is that it will always happen if there is a network issue. The window title changes to (unresponsive) and then the main window comes to the front.

Comment: Does anybody ever by chance pass the `SWP_NOOWNERZORDER` flag? That would cause normal z-ordering rules to be violated.

Comment: This is just a regular .NET app and it only seems to happen on Windows 7 (and the screenshot is a different app to the one I initially mentioned).  Can I tell if that flag was used to launch my dialog?